# member of class T is an instantiation of template class with template argument T

Tags: c++

So I am in process of coding class for some graph structure (suffix tree), and I encountered this difficult thing: a node should have pointers, one pointing on its parent, and also a set of pointers to its sons. I am using smart pointers to avoid errors with memory, and here is the thing: I write

```
class node { 
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<node> parent; 
    ...
};
```

I guess there is a term for this thing. Like self-referencing, or whatever. When I wrote it, initialy i was confident, that there will be an error, but no it had been successfully compiled. I was curious, can i write something like that:

```
class some_class_2{ 
    ...
    std::vector<some_class_2> some_vector; 
    std::string string_; 
    some_class() { 
        string_ = "lol";
        some_vector = std::vector<some_class>(10); 
    }
 };
```

Its appeared that the answer on this question is yes. So when i launched the test programm which had been succesfully compiled, of course it wouldn't stop, maybe i waited not enough and it should throw me some memory related error.

So the question is, how you should handle with this kind of things in c++? Isn't it strange that those things allowed in c++? Is it normal to put std::shatre_ptr inside some_class? How to write safe code, where errors like in some_class_2 are avoided, and what is the best way to 
represent graph structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language did not allow *any* use of `node` inside the definition of `node`, then there would be no way to create linked data structures such as lists and trees. In order for the language to be useful, it has to allow such constructs as:

```
struct node {
    int key;
    node* next;
};
```

On the other hand, the language cannot allow this:

```
struct node {
    int key;
    node next;
};
```

because then a `node` object would contain an infinite nested sequence of `node` objects and be infinitely large.

The way the language deals with this is to allow members of classes only to be *complete* types. A complete type's size is known. A class type is not complete until its full definition has been seen. So `node` is not complete *inside* its own definition, so you cannot put a `node` member inside a `node` object. But `node*` is complete even when `node` is not complete yet.

Some standard library templates can be used with complete types. The smart pointers, `std::unique_ptr<T>`, `std::shared_ptr<T>`, and `std::weak_ptr<T>`, are allowed to have incomplete `T`, since they have pointer semantics. However, `std::vector` does *not* allow its template parameter to be incomplete, and the result is undefined behaviour. The way to avoid this is to just *not write it* (it's not that hard).

Comment: Thank you, that is really clarifies all.

Comment: @Bars Please accept this answer if it solved your problem